# How may i specified cascade in hibernate mapping for bi-directional many-to-one?

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate-mapping, cascade

Hi i have some question about hibernate mapping and following saving operations.

I have Dealer.class which this properties:

```
public class Dealer extends Persistent {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 306594798010394718L;

private Domain domain;
private Integer status;
private DealerData activeData;        // this property belongs to DealerData.class
private Set<DealerData> historyData;
```

and his mapping is look like this

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="sk.bantip.hotel.server.dao.book.Dealer" table="book_dealer" dynamic-update="true" select-before-update="true">
    <id column="idBook_dealer" name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>

    <many-to-one name="activeData" column="idBook_dealerData"
        class="sk.bantip.hotel.server.dao.book.DealerData" />
    <set name="historyData" inverse="true">
        <key column="idBook_dealer" />
        <one-to-many class="sk.bantip.hotel.server.dao.book.DealerData" />
    </set>
    <property name="status" not-null="false" />
</class>
```

and DealerData.class

```
public class DealerData extends Persistent {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 8424120040396958913L;

private String name;
private String registration;
private String taxNumber;
private Long authorUserId;
.... many other props
```

and DealerData hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="sk.bantip.hotel.server.dao.book.DealerData" table="book_dealerData" dynamic-update="true" select-before-update="true" >
    <id column="idBook_dealerData" name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="name" not-null="true" />
    <property name="registration" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="taxNumber" not-null="true" />
    <property name="timestamp" not-null="true"  />
    <property name="authorUserId" column="idAuthor" not-null="true" update="false"/>
    <many-to-one name="dealer" column="idBook_dealer"
        not-null="true" class="sk.bantip.hotel.server.dao.book.Dealer" update="false" />

</class>
```

based on this my mapping i dont know where exactly i must defined `cascade="save-update"` operation. when i want save properties from form DealerData via JSF input fields and submit whole page, this statement must be inside `<many-to-one>` tag for DealerData or Dealer?

also i have Foreign key for DealerData as NULL in Dealer. and Foreign key for Dealer in DealerData is check as NOT-NULL, I want save DealerData value and follow on this must be save also a Dealer. so ID for Dealer must be generated too, but dont know how, because i got for FK column **Column 'id_dealer' cannot be null**

Can somebody help me with this,also how i construct save method corectly so both classes will be save in this method? Thanks a lot for advice.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
<bag name="Log" cascade="delete" inverse="true" order-by="DateEntry ASC">
    <key column="complaint" />
    <one-to-many class="ComplaintLog" />
</bag>
```

or

```
<many-to-one name="Status" class="ProcessStatus" cascade="none" not-null="true" />
```

when you set up the columns in the [class].hbm.xml mappings file

Answer (score 0):

Please erase extends from your class code 
give  in the  code